# How to modify the deployment plan in Apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

Storm automatically deploy every resources. But, for research, I want to do control the deployment of workers and tasks in apache storm. 
For example, a machine has four workers. In the machine, worker A processes bolt1 and Worker B processes bolt2 and so on... 
I want to control it for myself

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: You you provide a custom scheduler: https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/DemoScheduler.java